# Specific web page doesn't load (empty page) HTML and CSS with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I started working with Selenium, it works for any website I tried except one ([myvisit.com](https://myvisit.com/)) that doesn't load the page.
It opens Chrome but the page is empty. I tried to set number of delays but it still doesn't load.
When I go to the website on a regular Chrome (without Selenium) it loads everything.

Here is my simple code, not sure how to continue from that:

```py
import os
import random
import time

# selenium libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import ChromiumOptions


def delay():
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,3))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd()+"\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://myvisit.com")

delay()
delay()
delay()
delay()
```

I also tried to use `ChromiumOptions` with flags like `--no-sandbox` but it didn't help:

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: I wrote it in the code: https://myvisit.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd()+"\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe",options=options)
```

Simply add the argument to remove it from determining it's an automation.

Comment: Cool, how did you knew that? I searched for something to point it.